# How to find my files

Tags: installation

So this is the first time I'm using Linux, and I can't quite figure it all out. The only issue I'm having is that I cannot find the files I had from when I was using Windows. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't wipe the disk during install? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows partition, if present, are visible from our file manager named Nautilus.

#### Example:

[image]

On the left side there are shortcuts to directories, amongst them are also Windows partitions.

You can get to Nautilus by pressing the folder icon on the launcher or by pressing the Windows key and then search for nautilus.